# How to update field from required to optional using vapor (fluent migration)?

Tags: swift, database-migration, vapor, vapor-fluent, server-side-swift

I'm use vapor 4

```
struct MakeRegionOptional: AsyncMigration {
    
    func prepare(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("Attraction")
            .updateField("region", .string)
            .update()
    }
    
    func revert(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema("Attraction")
            .field("region", .sql(.default("")))
            .update()
    }
    
}
```

also adding migrations in the configuration file update table model.

```
app.migrations.add(MakeRegionOptional())
```

// Attraction model for table

```
final class Attraction: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "Attraction"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    
    //Before
    //@Field(key: "region")
    //var region: String
    
    // after make optional
    @OptionalField(key: "region")
    var region: String?
    
    init() { }
    
    init(id: UUID? = nil, region: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.region = region
    }
     }
```

I'm trying to make optional region field using migration. But my code is not working maybe my migration is wrong. Anyone knows how to make working on this migration?

Comment: When you say 'not working', what do you mean? What is the original type? Is there an error?

Comment: Original type is String and not get error but show below debug code

  [ DEBUG ] ALTER TABLE "Attraction" ALTER COLUMN "region" SET DATA TYPE TEXT [] [database-id: psql] (FluentPostgresDriver/FluentPostgresDatabase.swift:47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update()` enables you to change a column from optional, to `.required` but not the other way. Something like `.notRequired` would be useful here, but it doesn't exist!

The easiest way is to use a raw sql query to alter the column.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try your suggestion